# Pushwoosh / Phonegap, No sound, vibration and wake lock with push notifications on Android

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I've integrated pushwoosh sdk to send GCM push notifications on Android with PhoneGap.
I can receive notifications on my device but there is no sound, no vibration, wake lock and no led.

Here you can find my permissions on my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
  package="MY_PACKAGE_NAME" android:versionName="1.1" android:versionCode="5" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<permission
     android:name="MY_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission
     android:name="MY_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission
     android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="MyApp" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MY_PACKAGE_NAME.MESSAGE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushWebview"/>
    <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.MessageActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushHandlerActivity"/>

    <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="MY_PACKAGE_NAME"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushGCMIntentService"/>

</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/></manifest>
```

This is my init function:

```
function initPushwoosh() {
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
pushNotification.onDeviceReady();

//projectid: "GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID", appid : "PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID"
pushNotification.registerDevice({ projectid: "MY_PROJECT_ID", appid : "MY_PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID" },
                                function(status) {
                                    var pushToken = status;
                                    console.warn('push token: ' + pushToken);
                                },
                                function(status) {
                                    console.warn(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
                                });

document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
                            var title = event.notification.title;
                            var userData = event.notification.userdata;

                            if(typeof(userData) != "undefined") {
                                console.warn('user data: ' + JSON.stringify(userData));
                            }

                            navigator.notification.alert(title);
                            pushNotification.stopGeoPushes();
                          });}
```

Here instead, you can find the example (which I followed) of pushwoosh: [pushwoosh example](https://github.com/shaders/phonegap-cordova-push-notifications/tree/master/Android)

Where I wrong?

Thanks,
Daniele

Comment: Sure, I edited the question adding the init function.

Comment: @Daniele I am also trying the same thing. But I am not even recieving notifications . plzz help me.! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to do some Java to achieve this.

Go to Android project, find `PushNotifications` class, located at `/src/com/pushwoosh/plugin/pushnotifications/` and seek this line:

```
mPushManager = new PushManager(cordova.getActivity(), 
    params.getString("appid"), params.getString("projectid"));
```

then add following lines:

```
mPushManager.setVibrateNotificationType(VibrateType.ALWAYS);
mPushManager.setSoundNotificationType(SoundType.ALWAYS);
```

**EDIT:** Or you can send the sound in the notification itself:

```
"android_sound" : "soundfile", // Optional. Sound file name in the "res/raw" folder, do not include the extension
```

see: [[1]](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/#PushserviceAPI-Method%2Fmessages%2Fcreate)